# Adding a extra item to JSON.parse object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to add extra item to my JSON array.

My data returned from js-cookie...

```
var data = Cookies.getJSON('_basket');
```

If I `console.log(data)` this is what is returned...

[image]

So if I `console.log(data.basket)` this is what is returned...

[image]

What I'm trying to do is add an extra item to the `basket` object.

If I wanted to add an item to the `basket` with the `id 9` and `qty 3`.

My `console.log(data.basket)` would look like this...

[image]

What the best way to add items to the object using javascript/jquery?

Here is my full code in [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshmoto/sfpht69k/). See line 32 as to where I am trying to add my new item to the data.basket object. You have to click `Add to basket` button to create a cookie before seeing the console logs.

```js
// document ready
(function($) {


  // product index sidebar open toggle
  $(document).on('click', '.basket-add', function(e) {

    var product_id = $(this).data('id');
    var product_qty = $('#product_qty_' + product_id).val();
    var basket = {};

    // if basket cookie exists
    if (Cookies.get('_basket')) {

      // basket cookie data
      var data = Cookies.getJSON('_basket');
      
      // if product exists in basket
      if (data.basket[product_id]) {

        console.log('product exists in basket');
        
        console.log(data.basket);

      } else {
      
       console.log('product does not exist basket');

        // add new id to array
        console.log(data.basket);
        
        // this is where i'm trying to add an new item to data.basket
        
        /*
        
        data['basket'] = product_id
        
        data.basket[product_id] = {
          qty: product_qty
        }; 
        
        */
        
        console.log(data.basket);

      }

    } else {

      // create new basket array
      basket[product_id] = {
        qty: product_qty
      };

      // create new cookie
      Cookies.set('_basket', {
        domain: document.domain,
        basket: basket
      });

    }

    // prevent link defaults
    e.preventDefault();

  });


})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.2.1/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  7. Fondue Kit 39.00 <button class="basket-add" data-id="7">Add to basket</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="product_qty_7" />
</div>

<div>
  9. Dapper Chap 25.00 <button class="basket-add" data-id="9">Add to basket</button>
  <input type="number" value="1" id="product_qty_9" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (data.basket[product_id]) {

        console.log('product exists in basket');

        data.basket[9] = {
          qty: "3"
        };

        console.log(data.basket);

      }
```